# Summing values based on column and row titles

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2011

Currently using MS Excel for Mac 2011. I have been trying with no luck to make a formula that sums all values in an array that have a particular column title and row title. Row titles are unique, but column titles may repeat. Here's what I mean by this:

[Excel table hosted at imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q6YUT.png)

Trying to paste the Excel data as text in case the imgur link doesn't work, sorry it may be hard to see:

```
       Source data                      Summary
    Red Blue  Green Red             Red BlueGreen
Book    1   2   2   2       Book    3   2   2
Cake    2   7   7   2       Cake    4   7   7
Jeep    3   3   3   3       Jeep    6   3   3
```

In the above example, the summary table (which is in another sheet in the same workbook) should show the sum of values where, for example, the labels Book and Red both apply to a given cell. I have a big table with many row labels, and more will be added by users of the spreadsheet, so I can't use "Book", need to use a cell reference.

When I try using SUMIFS, I get an error message. I've tried using SUMPRODUCT, as well as a combination of INDEX and two MATCH functions, but I've so far failed with all attempts to get the expected results. No luck finding the answer through Google or SuperUser search.

This seems like it should be incredibly simple...

Comment: Will the rows be unique.  I see that the columns can double, but do the rows double?  Can there be more than 1 `Book`

Comment: What error are you getting when you use SUMIFS? Please also share what have you tried with SUMIFS.

Comment: @ScottCraner the rows are unique. However, the order of the rows may not be the same on the data and summary sheets. Right now I'm using =SUMIF('data'!$B$1:$CZ$1,C$3,'data'!$B4:$CZ4) which works for row 4 (row 3 in this example has the column title text to search for in the data table), and so on for each following row, but requires that the rows remain in the same order.

Comment: @pat2015 I get the #VALUE error. I've tried a few things with SUMIFS but didn't keep note of them. I know I tried this setup though: =SUMIFS('data'!B4:L30,'data'!B1:L1,'summary'!C$3,'data'!A4:A30,'summary'!A5)

In the above formula, 'data'!B1:L1 is the row of column titles that can repeat, 'summary'!C$3 is the cell with the column title that needs to match the aforementioned column titles in the data table, 'data'!A4:A30 is the unique row titles, 'summary'!A5 is the cell with the row title that needs to match the aforementioned row titles in the data table.

Answer (score 0):

If I get right what you are asking for It should be like this:

NOTE: (You should set the columns to apropiate):

```
=SUMIF('data'!$A$2:$Z$2;"RED";'data'!$A4:$Z4) 'This will add eveything in red
```

The you could drag this formula. Also if you reference your item in the summary table and lock the column you could also drag the items and calculate at the same time.

cheers

Answer (score 0):

Use this that will select the correct row and use SUMIF to capture the correct values horizontally.

```
=SUMIF($B$1:$E$1,I$1,INDEX($B:$E,MATCH($H2,$A:$A,1),0))
```

The `INDEX($B:$E,MATCH($H2,$A:$A,1),0)`  Returns the whole row in columns B:E to the SUMIFS.

[image]